# Open a program via batch file if there is no connection

Tags: batch-file, connection, batch-processing

I want to open a program only if there is no internet connection and I want to do it with a batch file..
I had in mind something like this:

```
if (! www.google.com) {start myprogram.exe} 
else {echo "The computer is connected to the internet"}
```

But I've never-depth study of the command windows, can someone tell me how to write this little "program"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ping somewhere and check whether the ping worked. For ping, errorlevel 1 = failure, errorlevel 0 = success

```
ping -n 1 google.com > NUL
if errorlevel 1 (
    myprogram.exe
) else (
    echo The computer is connected to the internet
)
pause
```

Comment: It works fine!!
How can I prevent the window being closed before I can read the message and press ENTER (or any other key) to close it?